# How to set environment vars in IntelliJ for Gradle tasks

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

the easiest way to pass spring profiles to `gradle bootRun` is (for me) by environment variable (e.g. `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`), when run on commandline.

Unlike the *Application* configurations, the config for gradle tasks does not provide an input for environment variables.  And as *VM options* don't get picked up either as it seems, I can not run those tasks from the IDE.

I am aware, that I could start IntelliJ with the envvar set, but this seems rather cumbersome.

So what I need is the IntelliJ pendant for `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,testdb gradle bootRun`, unless there is a good reason, they have left this out.

System is linux, intellij 14.  The project in question is using springboot and I want to move over from running `main` in IntelliJ to running with *springloaded*+`bootRun` and separate `compileGroovy` calls as IntelliJ is not "understanding" the gradle file completely and therefor hides errors.

Comment: Perhaps Spring Boot (or its Gradle plugin) supports Java system properties as well?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser yes the easiest way around right now is to add `bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties` and use either VM or script params (`-Dspring...`).

Comment: Is there seriously no way to specify a set of environment variables along with a run configuration with Gradle in IntelliJ?

Comment: @jpierson: Indeed, I just wasted a good while looking for one, but there just isn't.  See: [IDEA-115426](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115426) and [IDEA-149801](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149801).

Comment: Did you ever figure it out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make the `System.properties` available in the `bootRun` (or other) tasks.

```
bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties
```

This way we can set in IntelliJ *VM Options* like `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`.

Comment: Does not work with gradle 4.2: `> Could not get unknown property 'bootRun' for root project 'api' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa That's because you dont have the spring boot plugin added to your project.  This is an example _for bootRun_ - if you use micronaut or something else, you have to use the proper task name.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution for setting up Spring environment variables / settings with Gradle / IntelliJ

Firstly, define a basic properties file, and then one based on your environment, such as:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:default.properties"),@PropertySource("classpath:${env}.properties")})
```

Int the above example, pay careful attention to the `@PropertySource("classpath:${env}.properties")`. This is an environment variable being pulled through.

Next, add a VM argument to IntelliJ (via the Gradle Tasks Run Configurations) - or as an argument via the gradle command line.

[image: How to add a VM argument to the Gradle run configuration]
Lastly, copy the properties across in the gradle task as @cfrick mentioned and @mdjnewman have correctly shown:

```
tasks.withType(org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask) {
    bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had success adding the following to my build.gradle file:

```
tasks.withType(org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask) {
    systemProperty('spring.profiles.active', 'local')
}
```

This allows `gradlew bootRun` to be run from IntelliJ without requiring any changes to the IntelliJ Run/Debug Configurations (and also from the command line without having to manually specify a profile).

Comment: thanks for the answer.  but i'd rather not put "my" config into the `build.gradle`