# Gradle Unable to Load Google playServicesVersion

Tags: java, android, gradle, firebase

I am attempting to compile my application and am receiving the below error:

[image]

I am not sure what is causing it, but I my intention is to have gradle-auto-update those dependencies my using the $playServicesVersion key.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172863/how-to-set-environment-vars-in-intellij-for-gradle-tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` references project level variables. Since you're creating a new project, these variables aren't going to be available. They can be defined in either the root `build.gradle` or project level `build.gradle` though the point of having them is to be able to use them across sub-modules so you should put them in your root `build.gradle`.

In root `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    playServicesVersion = "10.0.1"
}
```

Other SO post explaining more of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20436423/4548500.